# List of German words with hyphenation - source of existing file

Tags: dictionary, hyphenation

For a little software project of mine I'm looking for a list (file) of German words with hyphenation marks.

I know, that such a list must exist, as I used one in another project back in 2009. I still have that list, but I cannot find the source where I downloaded it then. Any hints on finding the source of that specific list -- or an possibly updated version -- (or another similar list) are appreciated.

Specifics of the list I already own: The list contains 426,367 entries of German word with hyphention marked by `-`. File size 7.085.309 Bytes, name (hopefully the original one) `wortliste.txt`. The begin and end of file (as example) shown here:

```
Aa-chen
Aa-che-ner
Aa-che-ne-rin
Aa-che-nern
Aa-che-ners
Aa-chens
Aa-dorf
Aal-bau-er
Aal-beck
Aal-be-stand
[...]
Zy-prio-ten
zy-prio-ti-schen
zy-prio-ti-scher
zy-prio-ti-sche
zy-pri-schen
zy-pri-sche
Zys-te
Zys-ten
Zy-to-sta-ti-ka
zzgl
```

Comment: https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/german-de-de-frami-dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

The German TeX user group [**Dante e.V.**](https://www.dante.de/) maintains a project about hyphenation:

http://projekte.dante.de/Trennmuster/WebHome

Its [git repository](http://projekte.dante.de/Trennmuster/RepoHaupt) contains a German [word list](https://repo.or.cz/wortliste.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/wortliste) (17 MiB, MIT licensed) of currently about 505,000 words with hyphenation markers.

The format of the list is slightly more complicated that the one of your version, e.g. it differentiates between "Haupttrennstellen" und "Nebentrennstellen" and is also able to handle cases like Brücke <=> Brük-ke. A documentation is in the repo.

Comment: That looks promising, thank you. Might consider this for my project.