# CMU für die deutsche Sprache gesucht | Deutsche Wörterliste mit Silbentrennung

Tags: vocabulary

Ich suche eine Liste an deutschen Wörtern und ihrer Silbentrennung ähnlich wie diese hier [CMU Dict](https://github.com/Alexir/CMUdict).

Ich brauche circa 30.000 Wörter, möglichst auch die am häufigsten vorkommenden, unterteilt nach [IPA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationales_Phonetisches_Alphabet) oder [APRABET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPABET), aber eben auch nach Silben.

Ich habe von der Uni Leipzig einen [Wortkorpus](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de?corpusId=deu_news_2022) gefunden, der enthält leider nur die Wörter selbst, allerdings keine IPA Schreibweise. Auch gibt es eine [CMUSphinx Liste](https://github.com/G10DRAS/German-G2P-and-Acoustic-Model/tree/master), welche die Aprabet-Schreibweisen enthält, hier fehlt jedoch die Silbentrennung.

Ich brauche wirklich eine Silbentrennung der IPA oder Aprabetschreibweise (möglichst nach Aussprache in Hochdeutsch). Unterteilungen der normalen Wörter (wie das im [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Hauptseite) zum Beispiel vorhanden ist) bringen mir nichts.

// EDIT: Die vermeindlich bereits beantwortete Frage [List of German words with hyphenation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73059/list-of-german-words-with-hyphenation-source-of-existing-file) löst nicht mein Problem. Die Webseite von [Dante E.V.](https://wiki.dante.de/doku.php?id=start) beinhaltet nach fehlender Förderung nicht mehr den genannten Datensatz. Ebenso wäre dieser Datensatz auch unzureichend, da hier nur eine Unterteilung im normalen Alphabet existiert. Die Unterteilung im IPA Alphabet ist jedoch wichtig, da ich letzten Endes die Wörter in IPA Schrift brauche.

Comment: Was macht die Unterteilungen im Wiktionary unbrauchbar, wodurch unterscheiden sie sich wesentlich von anders aufgeführter Silbentrennung?

Comment: Am Ende benötige ich eine Liste an Worten unterteilt in Silben und geschrieben in IPA. Wie ich da hinkomme, das ist das Problem. Die Unterteilung vom Wiktionary bringt mir nichts, da ich das nur händisch übertragen könnte auf die IPA Schreibweise. Aber bei 30k Wörtern (eigenlicht hätte ich gerne 300k+) ist das zu viel manuelle Arbeit.

Comment: Vielleicht noch als Zusatz: Warum brauche ich überhaupt IPA? Ich schreibe an einem kleinen Projekt, welches deutsche Wörter reduziert auf eine Silbe. Welche Silbe das ist, entscheide ich anhand eines Klangraphen. Das bedeutet, es geht mir nicht darum wie Wörter geschrieben werden, sondern wie sie klingen und dass sie aussprechbar sind. Um diesen Klanggraphen zu erstellen, brauche ich die IPA Schreibweise der Wörter.

Comment: Danke für die Erläuterung

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of German words with hyphenation - source of existing file](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73059/list-of-german-words-with-hyphenation-source-of-existing-file)

Comment: not quite. for one, the referenced syllabel database isn't available anymore there. And second, this is only syllabels in the normal alphabet. I need however syllabels in IPA.

Comment: Da Du ja Wörter in Lautschrift suchst und diese sich teilweise regional unterscheidet (Bsp.: "Mathematik" wird in Deutschland anders als in Österreich ausgesprochen, ebenso "Kaffee"), wäre es nützlich, anzugeben, welche Aussprache Du als für Deine Zwecke verbindlich ansiehst.

Comment: Habe den Hinweis in der Frage hinzugefügt. Interessiert bin ich an Hochdeutscher Aussprache

Comment: Ich verstehe, warum die von mir vorgeschlagene Antwort nicht geeignet ist. Nur der Vollständigkeit halber sei aber angemerkt, dass mein dortiger Kommentar unter der Frage auf eine andere Liste verlinkt, die noch existiert. (Dass mein erster Kommentar hier auf Englisch erscheint, liegt daran, dass es sich um einen [automatisch eingefügten Textbaustein](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1809/kommentarbausteine-auf-deutsch-oder-englisch) handelt.)

Comment: "Hochdeutsch" ist sowohl bundesdeutsches wie österreichisches wie auch schweizer Deutsch. Das ist ähnlich wie mit britischem und amerikanischem Englisch, da ist auch nicht eines "korrekter" als das andere - nur anders.

Comment: @ccprog Ich habe mir die OXT Datei aus dem Kommentar angesehen. Der Inhalt dieser Zipdatei besteht aus Deutschen Wörtern, Erklärungen der Wörter und Trennungspunkten abgeleitet aus dem TeX Hyphentation. Allerdings erfüllt dieser Datensatz zwei Dinge nicht. 1. es ist keine 100% Silbentrennung, Wörter wie Metalllegierung werden nur in Metall-Legierung aufgeteilt, jedoch nicht in Silben. 2. Die Unterteilung existiert nicht im IPA Alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary hat, wie jede Wikimedia-Seite, eine Programmierschnittstelle: https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php

Dieses API kannst du verwenden, um darauf mit einem von dir zu schreibenden Programm zuzugreifen. Auf diese Weise kannst du von allen Wortformen, die in Wiktionary eingetragen sind, die IPA-Lautschrift ermitteln. Das sind derzeit etwas mehr als 1,1 Millionen Wortformen, davon über 140.000 Grundformen.

Nachdem die Unterteilung von Wörtern in Sprechsilben aufgrund der Sonorität der einzelnen Phone erfolgt, ist es auch relativ einfach, anhand dieser Sonorität die Silbengrenzen zu bestimmen, wenn man erstmal die Lautschrift hat. Dazu liefert der Wikipedia-Artikel über [Silben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silbe) relativ viele brauchbare Informationen.

---

Ich muss dich aber auch auf ein paar Fallstricke deines Plans aufmerksam machen:

1. Deine Anfrage klingt so, als wärst du nur an den Grundformen interessiert, weil du nur von »Wörtern« sprichst. Aber vergiss dabei nicht, dass Wortformen wie *»suche«, »eine«, »deutschen«, »Wörtern«* und *»ihrer«,* die alle innerhalb der ersten 10 Wörter deines Postings vorkommen, keine Grundformen sind, aber trotzdem häufig verwendet werden. Viele von ihnen gehören zu den häufigsten 30.000 Wortformen, also zu der Menge, die du untersuchen möchtest.

   Die Wortformen *»ist«, »des«, »sich«* und noch ein paar andere gehören sogar zu den 30 häufigsten deutschen Wortformen, obwohl sie keine Grundformen sind.

   Einige Silben kommen sogar nur in Wortformen vor, die keine Grundformen sind, z.B. die Endsilbe -elst (»du handelst, vermittelst und trödelst«).
2. Es kommt manchmal vor, dass es mehrere unterschiedliche Aussprachen für dasselbe Wort gibt, die eine unterschiedliche Anzahl von Silben haben können.

   - Beispiel 1: **gehen**

     - In Deutschland in der gehobenen Sprache mit 2 Silben: [ˈɡeːən] ([ˈɡeː] und [ən])
     - In Deutschland in der alltäglichen Spontansprache und in Österreich so gut wie immer nur 1 Silbe: [ɡeːn]
   - Beispiel 2: **Bibliothek**
     Hier ist die Schreibweise in IPA-Symbolen eindeutig: [biblioˈteːk] aber die Anzahl der Silben ist mehrdeutig

     - Es könnten 4 Silben sein: [bib], [li], [o], [ˈteːk]
     - Es könnten aber auch nur 3 Silben sein: [bib], [lio], [ˈteːk]

   Beachte, dass in den Zweifelsfällen, die zu dieser Kategorie gehören, jeweils beide Varianten korrekt sind.
3. ambisyllabische Konsonanten ([Silbengelenke](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silbengelenk))

   Das sind Konsonanten, die nur einmal gesprochen werden, aber zugleich das letzte Phon der einen und das erste Phon der nächsten Silbe sind.

   - Beispiel 1: **alle** [ˈalə]

     - Möglichkeit 1: [ˈa] und [lə]
     - Möglichkeit 2: [ˈal] und [ə]
   - Beispiel 2: **kommen** [ˈkɔmən]

     - Möglichkeit 1: [ˈkɔ] und [mən]
     - Möglichkeit 2: [ˈkɔm] und [ən]

   Beachte, dass in den Fällen, wo ein Silbengelenk vorliegt, keine der beiden möglichen Trennungen korrekt ist. Auch der Ausweg, das Silbengelenk bei der Trennung beiden Silben zuzuweisen (also [ˈal] + [lə] bzw. [ˈkɔm] + [mən]) ist falsch, weil das Silbengelenk ja nur einmal ausgesprochen wird.

Comment: Das Wort Bibliothek wird normalerweise Bi-blio-thek getrennt. Das zweite B gehört zur zweiten Silbe, nicht zur ersten.

Comment: Du spricht wichtige Punkte an, jedoch keine Lösung zu meinem Problem.

Eine Liste an Worten mit ihren dazugehörigen IPA Lautschriften zu erlangen, ist nicht das Problem. Sondern, diese IPA Lautschrift auch in Silben getrennt zu erhalten. Ja, die Sonorität der Silben bietet eine Möglichkeit, selbst diese Unterteilung vorzunehmen, allerdings kann dies zu vielen Probleme führen (wie du in drei Beispielen aufzeigst). Deshalb suche ich eine Liste, die diese Unterteilung bereits vorgenommen hat.

Comment: Ein letzter Punkt: Du sprichst an, dass es mir um Grundformen von Wörtern geht. Das stimmt nicht. Ich bin an allen Wörtern und ihren Plural/Genus/etc Formen interessiert.

Die genannte Mindestanzahl an 30.000 Wörtern bezieht sich hier auf die 30.000 meist benutzten Wörter, unabhängig ob in Grundform, mehrfach vorhanden in verschiedenen Formen, oder nicht.

Comment: Eine Liste, in der jemand für dich bereits all die genannten Probleme gelöst hat, gibt es leider nicht. Ich hätte so etwas selbst vor einiger Zeit benötigt. Ich wollte damals von jeder Sprache mit mehr als 50 Millionen Sprechern die jeweils häufigsten Silben, aber es gibt weder für Deutsch, noch für andere Sprachen, Wortlisten mit phonetisch getrennten Silben, und auch keine Listen häufiger Silben. Und ich vermute, dass es das ganz einfach deswegen nicht gibt, weil einige der von mir genannten Probleme (z.B. das der Silbengelenke) schlichtweg nicht zufriedenstellend gelöst werden können.

Comment: So, wie ich dein Projekt verstanden habe, hast du aber auch mit einem ganz anderen Problem zu kämpfen. Du musst eine Definition dafür finden, was denn überhaupt ein gesprochenes Wort ist. Dafür gibt es nämlich keine klare Definition. Die Existenz von Fragen, die zu ergründen suchen, ob man "wieviele" oder "radfahren" zusammen oder getrennt schreibt, belegt, dass die Frage, was ein Wort ist, weit unklarer ist, als man auf den ersten Blick vermuten würde. Denn die Regeln, die festlegen, wann man zwischen zwei Bestandteile ein Leerzeichen *schreibt* sind sehr willkürlich (und wurden auch ...

Comment: ... schon mehrmals verändert), aber vor allem sagen so gut wie nichts darüber aus, ob man beim *Sprechen* eine Pause macht oder nicht. Wörter wie *»Krepppapier«* und *»Betttuch«* spricht man mit klar hörbarer Pause, es sind also jeweils 2 gesprochene Wörter. Andererseits gibt es auch Wörter, bei denen kein Zweifel daran besteht, dass man sie getrennt schreibt, trotzdem werden sie im Normalfall als nur ein Wort ausgesprochen ("kann nicht" [kan nɪçt] -> [kanɪçt]; "muss sein" [mʊs zaɪ̯n] -> [mʊsaɪ̯n]).

Comment: Ich glaube, da kann man sich auch in den Details verlieren. Mir genügt lediglich die Standardunterteilung nach Silben wie sie im Duden steht. Alle Arten von Wörtern werde ich so oder so nicht umfassen können, deshalb fokusiere ich mich auf die meist genutzten